# How to find the value of alpha in this curcuit?

Tags: current, circuit-analysis, current-source, circuit-theory

[image: question]

I have tried to solve this way but i am not sure how to proceed from here:

[![tried solution][2]][2]

Comment: None of the resistors is in a parallel connection.

Comment: If the circuit i have drawn is not correct then what will be the approch

Comment: Sorry, you are going to have to try harder than that. Make another attempt to solve the problem and get back to us if you get stuck.

Comment: In this case, you need to solve the system of equations. Notice that you know the voltage across the current source (180W/9A = 20V)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a \$9\:\text{A}\$ current source that leaves from the top end by only two paths and arrives to the bottom end via only two paths. You have two unknowns, \$\alpha\$ and \$I_x\$. So this feels ***convenient*** to me. Let's walk through the two paths using KVL to produce two equations. The first equation walks around the left side loop's KVL and the second equation walks around the right side loop's KVL.

$$\begin{align*}
\left(9\:\text{A}-I_x\right)\cdot 2\:\Omega + \left(9\:\text{A}-I_x +\alpha\:I_x\right)\cdot 2\:\Omega&=V_{9\:\text{A}}\\\\
I_x\cdot 1\:\Omega+\left(I_x-\alpha\: I_x\right)\cdot 2\:\Omega&=V_{9\:\text{A}}
\end{align*}$$

These are easily reduced to:

$$\begin{align*}
\left(2 -\alpha\right)\cdot I_x&=18\:\text{A}-\frac{V_{9\:\text{A}}}{2\:\Omega}\\\\
\left(3-2\:\alpha\right)\cdot I_x&=\frac{V_{9\:\text{A}}}{1\:\Omega}
\end{align*}$$

Which is easily solved simultaneously for \$\alpha\$ and for \$I_x\$.

Note that G36, in a comment I upped above, points out that you know something about the voltage difference across the \$9\:\text{A}\$ current source. Use that information to provide the value for \$V_{9\:\text{A}}\$.

---

Just look at the \$9\:\text{A}\$ source for a moment. It splits into two parts.

1. \$9\:\text{A}-I_x\$ goes to the left, through a \$2\:\Omega\$ resistor at the top left, where it then combines with an arriving current, \$\alpha\: I_x\$, that must be added to it before going through the remaining \$2\:\Omega\$ resistor at the bottom left. Clearly, the voltage drop across the first \$2\:\Omega\$ resistor is \$\left(9\:\text{A}-I_x\right)\cdot 2\:\Omega\$ and the voltage drop across the second \$2\:\Omega\$ resistor is \$\left(9\:\text{A}-I_x+\alpha\: I_x\right)\cdot 2\:\Omega\$.
2. \$I_x\$ goes to the right, through a \$1\:\Omega\$ resistor at the top right, splitting into two parts: \$\alpha\: I_x\$ and also therefore also \$I_x-\alpha\: I_x\$ that goes through a \$2\:\Omega\$ resistor at the bottom right. Clearly, the voltage drop across the \$1\:\Omega\$ resistor is \$I_x\cdot 1\:\Omega\$ and the voltage drop across the \$2\:\Omega\$ resistor is \$\left(I_x-\alpha\: I_x\right)\cdot 2\:\Omega\$.

You should be able to see why the current split occurs at the top end of the \$9\:\text{A}\$ current source such that \$I_x\$ goes to the right and \$9\:\text{A}-I_x\$ goes to the left. You should also clearly understand that the sum of the two currents arriving at the bottom end of the \$9\:\text{A}\$ current source must combine to make up that same \$9\:\text{A}\$ current source magnitude. There is no option, otherwise. The other current source, \$\alpha\: I_x\$, subtracts current from node and injects it into another node.

You merely need to remain consistent about the indicated ***directions*** in the schematic. If the current arrow says a current is *leaving* a node, then you subtract it. If the current arrow says a current is *entering* a node, then you add it. Do not try and impose some mental "sense" about what might "really" be happening. Your intuition is irrelevant, here. Just follow the directions indicated and assume they are correct. If they are NOT correct, then the sign will be negative and that will tell you that the current is actually going opposite to what you assumed from the indicated arrows. But that is fine. The point is to form up the equations in a consistent manner.

Comment: I have one question sir , why we are considering that the current alpha Ix to flow through the bottom 2ohm R not the top 2ohm R

Comment: @LaxmikantaNayak See my added note.

Comment: The outside alpha Ix i can take either through top or bottom ,thats ireespective right?

Comment: @LaxmikantaNayak I'm not sure about your question. You should simply stay consistent in the way you imagine. If you start by imagining that the current, \$I_x\$, is flowing from the top and through the \$1\:\Omega\$ resistor towards the right side node, then you ***must*** also imagine that the \$\alpha\:I_x\$ current is ***subtracted*** from it before what remains then goes through the following \$2\:\Omega\$ resistor. It *must* be subtracted because that is what the *arrow* says! You stay consistent. And on the left side, that same arrow says it becomes *added* entering that node.

Comment: Got it now ,thanks i am going to solve more problem on this to apply this concept and see all senarios

Answer (score 2):

Try using this schematic

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnelFP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Write a KVL around the two loops.

$$20V = I_XR_1+I_2R_2$$

$$20V = I_3R_3 +I_4R_4 $$

And express the current in terms of \$I_X\$.

For example \$I_3 = 9A - I_X\$

Comment: I am trying hard but cant able to understand what exactly would be my approch

Comment: I have two doubts : 1. Why we are taking the current in all registers as downward . 2. Why the current alpha Ix is not getting divided to flow throught top and bottom 2ohm register

Comment: From what see your solution is right, the alpha is equal to 4. As for your question Jonk explain it very well.  In general, the current direction can be chosen arbitrarily because It's not always easy to know in advance what direction the current will flow. Don't worry about it, just choose an arbitrary direction  If you would have chosen the wrong direction the result will be negative, that's all.

Comment: Understood it conpletely now

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fW70rd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Jonk is correct in directing you to use consistent KCL arrows, 
because an intuitive estimate can be wrong, such as the solution above for a=4Ix which approaches infinity as Rx approaches 2 Ohms in a balanced bridge which cannot draw any more power from the 9A current as a 200W net load.